# Does MacBook Air 2012 WiFi support two spatial streams?

Tags: wifi, performance

The MacBook Air 2012 (13") has support for 802.11n 5 GHz, but I have never observed a Tx speed greater than 150 Mbps, which is attainable with a single spatial stream.

Does it support two streams for a total of 300 Mbps?

I can't find any mention of the max transfer rate for these models. The closest I can come to an answer is recalling that I *might* have seen the speed be reported as 130 Mbps which, if exact, [is only attainable with two streams on a 20 MHz channel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n-2009).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

300 Mbps speeds have been reported by the OS on certain networks, and the conclusion is yes, it uses two spatial streams.